# Concatenation multiple columns in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm doing a simple concatenation in SSIS.

For example I have a table like this:

```
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
| ID     | COL_A     | COL_B      | COL_C  |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
| 110-99 |           | APPLE      | Orange |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
| 111-01 | Mango     | Palm       |        |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
| 111-02 |           | Strawberry |        |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
| 111-05 | Pineapple | Guava      | Lemom  |
+--------+-----------+------------+--------+
```

I'm doing this in SSIS Derived column. Concatenation of 3 columns with Pipe `|`

```
COL_A +"|"+COL_B+"|"+COL_C
```

Actual Result:

```
|APPLE|Orange
MANGO|Palm|
|Strawberry|
Pineapple|Guava|Lemom
```

Expected Result:

```
APPLE|Orange
MANGO|Palm
Strawberry
Pineapple|Guava|Lemom
```

I'm not sure how to remove those extra `|` when the value is empty. I have tried using `CASE` but it is not working. Actually I don't know how to use `CASE` in Derived column expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute conditional logic in SSIS expressions using `?:` syntax. [? : (Conditional) (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) It works much like an inline `IFF`.

Along these lines:

```
boolean_expression ? returnIfTrue : returnIfFalse
```

In order to get your desired results, I think I'd use two derived column transformations. In the first one, I'd create the pipe delimited string, then in the second one, I'd trim off the trailing pipe if there was one after building the string. Otherwise, the conditional logic would get pretty hairy in order to avoid leaving a trailing delimiter.

Step one - If each column is `NULL` or an empty string, return an empty string. Otherwise, return the contents of the column with a pipe concatenated to it:

```
((ISNULL(COL_A) || COL_A == "") ? "" : COL_A + "|"
```

Repeat that logic for all three columns, putting this expression into your derived column (Line breaks added for readability here):

```
(((ISNULL(COL_A) || COL_A == "") ? "" : COL_A + "|" ) + 
(((ISNULL(COL_B) || COL_B == "") ? "" : COL_B + "|" ) + 
(((ISNULL(COL_C) || COL_C == "") ? "" : COL_C )     --No pipe here, since nothing follows.
```

Then, in the second transformation, trim the trailing pipes from the instances where the last column or two were empty:

```
(RIGHT(NewColumnFromAbove,1)=="|") ? LEFT(NewColumnFromAbove,LEN(NewColumnFromAbove)-1) : NewColumnFromAbove
```

On the other hand, if there are lots of columns, or if performance gets bogged down, I would strongly consider writing the concatenation into a stored procedure, using `CONCAT_WS`, and then invoke that from an `Execute SQL` task instead.

Comment: Thanks. It helped. I have to use `||` instead of `OR` and `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Sorry about the operator errors. I was working from memory. I've corrected the answer. But I'm glad it got you going in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, one option is `concat_ws()`, which ignores `null` values by design. If you have empty strings, your can turn them to `null` values with `nullif()`.

```
concat_ws(
    ' | ', 
    nullif(col_a, ''),
    nullif(col_b, ''),
    nullif(col_c, '')
)
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB. Unfortunately that is not available in SSIS :(